# trouble with updating my object

Tags: javascript

Hello I am pretty new at JavaScript and I am a little stuck right now.
The point of the project I'm doing is to create a card object and have methods that set a new face and suit. When I click the button to show my card it works however when I click the button to update my face and suit and reclick the button to show my card it doesn't show the updated info. I've been on this for quite a while now and still don't understand why it doesn't work. 
PLS HELP :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Object Oriented Programming</title>
  <script>
    function Card(suit, face) {
      this.suit = suit;
      this.face = face;
      this.card = face + ' of ' + suit;
      this.showCard = function() {
        alert(this.card);
      }
      this.setSF = function(newSuit, newFace) {
        this.suit = newSuit;
        this.face = newFace;
      }
    }

    var card1 = new Card("Diamonds", 8);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Show card" onclick="card1.showCard()" />
  <input type="button" value="Click to change the suit and face" onclick="card1.setSF('Hearts',5)" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. It's because you aren't updating `this.card` when you set the new card. So instead of alerting `this.card`, just alert `this.face + ' of ' + this.suit` which you did update, and remove `this.card` all together as it isn't really doing anything and is redundant.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Object Oriented Programming</title>
  <script>
    function Card(suit, face) {
      this.suit = suit;
      this.face = face;
      this.showCard = function() {
        alert(this.face + ' of ' + this.suit);
      }
      this.setSF = function(newSuit, newFace) {
        this.suit = newSuit;
        this.face = newFace;
      }
    }

    var card1 = new Card("Diamonds", 8);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Show card" onclick="card1.showCard()" />
  <input type="button" value="Click to change the suit and face" onclick="card1.setSF('Hearts',5)" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you might be getting tripped up is that `this.card = face + ' of ' + suit;` only happens once, and when you refer to `this.card` the second time, it doesn't just "go out and get those values". You might replace that initial assignment with a function, such as:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Object Oriented Programming</title>
  <script>
    function Card(suit, face) {
      this.suit = suit;
      this.face = face;
      // this.card = face + ' of ' + suit;
      this.combinedElements = function() {
        return this.suit + this.face;
      }
      this.showCard = function() {
        alert(this.combinedElements());
      }
      this.setSF = function(newSuit, newFace) {
        this.suit = newSuit;
        this.face = newFace;
      }
    }

    var card1 = new Card("Diamonds", 8);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Show card" onclick="card1.showCard()" />
  <input type="button" value="Click to change the suit and face" onclick="card1.setSF('Hearts',5)" />

</body>

</html>
```